# Missing Monit WebGUI

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, monit

I cannot for the life of me locate where the source files for the Monit WebGUI are stored. Does anyone know where in the file system this small web server is served from? Google has not been any help either.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to M/Monit?

Comment: No, just monit. Monit has a tiny WebGUI built in that runs off port 2812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the HTTP logic and HTML code is embedded in the C binary, as is indicated by the [Monit source code](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/src/8cdfafab71301d0fe478d24569c02ca0f118a5ea/src/http/cervlet.c?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).